# LocalPathPlanner PoseStamped

Tags: ros, pose, path, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

I want to use the data by the localpath planner.
The Data Type is nav_msgs/Path and I am using with my node a pointer to get for example the x coordinate:

```
ROS_INFO("Data x [%f]", pathConstPtr->pose[i].pose.position.x);
```

Which works fine, but I have no idea how I can find out how many poses I have?

Are there some kind of methods to get the size of the posestamped?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209486/localpathplanner-posestamped/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can call the size() method on pathConstPtr->poses : arrays in messages are mainly handled as std::vector from cpp.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-05-19**:
thaaaanks mate, saved me a lot of trouble :)